ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal in TensorFlow 2.10 with Python 3.8 on Windows
I'm trying to set up TensorFlow in a conda environment on my Windows machine, but I'm encountering an ImportError related to _pywrap_tensorflow_internal. Here are the details of my setup and the error message I'm getting:
Environment:
OS: Windows
Python version: 3.8.15 (packaged by conda-forge)
TensorFlow version: 2.10
CPU only (no GPU)
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable is installed

Steps to reproduce:
Created a conda environment named tf_env
Installed TensorFlow using pip install tensorflow==2.10
Tried to import TensorFlow in Python

Error message:
(tf_env) C:\Users\Ali Ahmed>python --version
Python 3.8.15

(tf_env) C:\Users\Ali Ahmed>python
Python 3.8.15 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Nov 22 2022, 08:43:00) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 77, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 62, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors for some common causes and solutions.
If you need help, create an issue at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues and include the entire stack trace above this error message.

